# JQuery: Replacing custom HTML tags with valid HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, templates

I'm currently working on an AJAX site where we use custom HTML tags to create template pages.

This is the HTML part:

```
<div id="main">
    <div>
        <ns:zone name="navigation" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <ns:zone name="page" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The above example works just fine, with the following substitution done by JQuery:

```
$("ns\\:zone").each(function()
    {
        $(this).replaceWith(getHtml($(this).attr("name")));
    }
);
```

However, you may have noticed the HTML code could look much better like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <ns:zone name="navigation" />
    <ns:zone name="page" />
</div>
```

Unfortunately, in that case, the first "zone" tag will be correctly replaced, but the second "zone" tag will disappear.
I don't think it's due to the browser (I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox) but rather to JQuery.
Could it be due to JQuery "rebuilding" the DOM tree, and deleting my "invalid" HTML tags?

I've also tried with JQuery's html() method instead of replaceWith(). The results are the same.

Do you see where the problem lies? It seems like JQuery *does* support custom HTML, but maybe not correctly? Should I setup my own xmlns?

As a side note: The website should allow the customer to very easily create a custom template, or to convert a bought website into a template for our application.
We are currently developing the web services in PHP, but we may partially move a part of the application to a glassfish server. Therefore, this mechanism should *not* rely on the server technology!
Quite obviously, the website should be as cross-browser as possible.

--

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Comment: I can hear all of your customers scream at you *"Where have my Google rankings gone!?"*

Comment: Hahah, good point! I have an idea in mind, that might be solution to that issue. Still needs testing.

Comment: There's rumors that Google actually evaluates AJAX calls ... But you'd wanna test that extensively before you go into production. Generally, though, you're way better off parsing templates server-side. If you absolutely want to use JS/jQuery for this purpose, consider setting up a dedicated node.js script - there are DOM modules available and it's incredibly fast.

Comment: Tags that are not part of HTML are not HTML and treating them as thought they were will give strange results. Surely the way to make this as customisable as possible is to manipulate *valid* tags inserted by the user <div data-zone="page" / <div class="zone-page" ... doing this means the document is *valid* html, is searchable & allows default content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably work if you did a proper closing:

```
<ns:zone name="navigation"></ns:zone>
<ns:zone name="page"></ns:zone>
```

Comment: This worked! Strange, I thought the shorthand tag closing like <br /> was "universal" and could be applied to any tag...

Out of curiosity: isn't there a way to make that shorthand tag closing work with the custom tags? I don't like to tell the customer "Yes it works, BUT you should do it like this and not like that"... :-)

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No it does not, the self closing tag is XML and not HTML, and it depends on your documents MIME type, but in general in XHTML, <foo /> is shorthand for <foo></foo>, but this only works in XML parsing mode and most documents are served as text/html.

In HTML 5, <foo /> just means <foo>. The slash is just syntactic sugar for people who are addicted to XML. The syntax is valid, but it is not a "self-closing tag". The distinction is important since (in the HTML syntax at least) <div /> means <div> in HTML 5 and not <div></div> as it does in XHTML. jQuery probably does what the browsers do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the '*' attribute in your select function to select all elements and then apply the $.each function on them! Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)

Something like this:

```
$('[*name]').each(function(){//do your stuff});
```

The code may be wrong in this case but the idea is the same!
Or use the $.find() function on them and after use the $.each function!

Your code just selects the first element, not all.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Interesting, but that would also select <input> tags and such, isn't it? I think I could filter out the results, but then my concern would be performance. I'll test it though, thanks for your answer!

Comment: You could add the "ns" attribute in front, like this "ns[*name]" and it will only select tags with 'ns' and attribute name, so, not all the inputs are selected